# Можно ли отследить присваивание результата выполнения метода?

Tags: c#

Условно есть `MyLib1.dll` в которой есть следующий метод:

```
public static int Sum(int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

Так же есть какой-то юзер моей библиотеки который вызывает этот метод. Могу ли я отследить **присваивание значения** которое вернет мой метод?

Т.е условно это выглядит так (в юзерском коде):

```
int result = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
```

После выполнения этого метода выделяется (возможно нет, но не суть) память под `result`, и в своей `MyLib1.dll` я хочу узнать было ли присваивание значения. Как это можно реализовать и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Вот если бы вы возвращали класс, то можно было бы какие-то обращения к нему контролировать. А тип-значение как вы отследите? Это просто "обезличенное" значение, не отличимое от других значений в программе. Что его вернули именно вы уже никакого значения дальше не имеет.

Comment: @CrazyElf жаль, думал можно как-нибудь `=` отслеживать при вызове методов возвращающих типы bcl :)

Comment: Какова конечная цель этого? Допустим, произошло присваивание - что должно произойти в вашей библиотеке? А если не произошло присваивание (но метод был вызван), тогда что должно произойти?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov никакой цели нет, просто интерес

Comment: Могу предложить вариант с `return ref`, в котором память под возвращённое значение не выделяется. | Подумав... Нет, не могу. Бред получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать операторы преобразования. [User-defined conversion operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

```
namespace MyLib
{
    public readonly struct MyNumber
    {
        private readonly int _number;

        public MyNumber(int number) => _number = number;

        public static implicit operator int(MyNumber number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("присваивание");
            return number._number;
        }
        public static implicit operator MyNumber(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("вызов");
            return new MyNumber(number);
        }

        public override string ToString() => _number.ToString();
    }

    public static class LibClass
    {
        public static MyNumber Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Перегружены операторы присваивания. В них мы можем вставить код, реагирующий на их вызов.

Я оба оператора сделал неявными (implicit), что не рекомендуется. Но для наших целей сойдёт.

---

Пробуем:

```
int x = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
```

Выдаст

```
вызов
присваивание
```

То есть можно узнать, было ли присваивание!

---

Если написать

```
MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
```

Результат будет

```
вызов
```

Присваивания нет!

---

Однако, если написать

```
var y = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
```

или, что равноценно

```
MyNumber z = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
```

Результат

```
вызов
```

То есть о присваивании в этом случае мы не узнаем.

Comment: Прям мои мысли прочитали, сейчас пытался как раз точно так же сделать. Нагуглил что `implicit`  неявно перегружает оператор присваивания (добавьте это в текст ответа, очень важный момент!). Думаю какими-нибудь свистоперделками из рефлексии можно попробовать добавить implicit для `Int32` (к сожалению по дефолту `op_Implicit` нет у инта), но у меня пока не получается. В целом результат устраивает

Comment: @Aarnihauta - в .net постепенно завозят давно нужные фичи. [.NET 7 Preview 5 – Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/). Но вроде бы до сих пор нельзя навесить на существующий тип такое преобразование.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, напишу.
Допустим, что в этой теме мы обсуждаем всякое странное!

Используем [Ref returns and ref locals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns).

В метод добавим ключевое слово `ref` в сигнатуру и в место возврата:

```
namespace MyLib
{
    public static class LibClass
    {
        static int c;

        public static ref int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            c = a + b;
            return ref c;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, если при вызове тоже использовать `ref`, переменная будет ссылаться на память, выделенную для поля `c`.

```
ref int x = ref MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
Console.WriteLine(x);

ref int y = ref MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 6);
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Это выведет:

```
10
11
11
```

Видно, что значение `x` поменялось при втором вызове.

А если не использовать `ref`:

```
int a = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 5);
Console.WriteLine(a);

int b = MyLib.LibClass.Sum(5, 6);
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

будет вывод:

```
10
10
11
```

В этом варианте значение `a` остаётся прежним.

---

Не знаю, зачём всё это. Ну а вдруг!